# How does one reconcile the fact that Avraham Avinu proselytized to non-Jews and yet Judaism is not a proselytizing religion?

Tags: gentiles, conversion-to-judaism, abraham, derabanan

I've read that Avraham Avinu proselytized to anyone he encountered, encouraging them to acknowledge HaShem as the Master of the Universe and express gratitude to Him. Yet, it is generally understood that Judaism is not a proselytizing religion. Are there any rabbinic explanations as to why Judaism doesn't proselytize even though its great progenitor actually proselytized?

Comment: He was informing them of the existence of G-d, he wasn't telling them to join the Jewish religion - it didn't exist?!

Comment: @Dov True. Then shouldn't it be so that, to honor what made Avraham Avinu beloved to HaShem and consequently establish a covenant with him, there should be a regular effort made to teach non-Jews about HaShem and the 7 Laws?

Comment: We do make an active effort - it is called being an אור לגוים - "a light unto the nations". This plus also making a kiddush Hashem.

Comment: @Dov If you found the cure to cancer would you keep it to yourself only and not share it with the rest of the world?

Comment: Of course not which is why Avraham shared the existence of G-d

Comment: We don't want the whole world to be Jewish, we want the whole world to be ethical monotheists. The latter is what Avraham was pushing.

Comment: @Shalom I just think that if we have the Torah, and if it's the ultimate truth, and if it is the word of God, written by God, then why don't we just share that with the world? If pious Jews are convinced that the Torah will make your life better, why not share that and make more converts. Why not actively seek out converts?

Comment: @Shalom If you found the cure to cancer would you share it with the world or keep it to yourself? Any honest person would share that. Why not share the Torah, the cure to all suffering? Sharing Torah means making more converts, means more Jews. More Jews studying Torah will bring the messianic age faster. If you really want the messiah to come now, make converts!

Comment: @Dov Abraham didn't have the Torah. If he had the Torah I bet he would have shared that, too.

Answer (score 8):

I think there is a subtle difference.

To proselyte is to ask/convince someone to convert to a religion. In the case of Avraham there was no Jewish religion, it was just an acknowledgment of G-d's existence.

Rambam in [Mishneh Torah, Hilchos Avodah Zara 1:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Foreign_Worship_and_Customs_of_the_Nations.1.3?ven=Mishneh_Torah,_trans._by_Eliyahu_Touger._Jerusalem,_Moznaim_Pub._c1986-c2007&lang=bi) explains that everyone worshipped idols until Avraham came on the scene. Avraham had this life-changing epiphany whereby he came and called Hashem "Lord" (See [Berachos 7b](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.7b.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

It was a sincere desire to bring the awareness of G-d into the world that drove Avraham. The midrash in [Bereishis Rabbah 39:16](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereshit_Rabbah.39.16?lang=bi) says precisely this:

> וַיִּקְרָא בְּשֵׁם ה', מְלַמֵּד שֶׁהִקְרִיא שְׁמוֹ שֶׁל הַקָּדוֹשׁ בָּרוּךְ הוּא בְּפִי כָּל בְּרִיָה
>
> "And he called the name of Hashem" - this teaches that he caused the Name of G-d to be called upon by all people.

Indeed, the Gemara in [Menachos 53a](https://www.sefaria.org/Menachot.53a.16?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) writes equally,

> אמר לה טובתי בל עליך איני מחזיק טובה אלא לאברהם יצחק ויעקב שהודיעוני תחלה בעולם
>
> G-d said, "I give credit to Avraham, Yitzchak and Yaakov, who were the first to make Me known in the world.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion that it is written that Abraham converted is not the same conversion that we are talking about today.

Abraham our father according to the book of the Khazari he belongs to a holy seed from which came the people of Israel, but it is clear that all those who converted during his time did not become Jews, and that is because there was no Judaism yet, and the only thing that existed was the 7 mitzvot of the sons of Noah, and indeed even today it is of great importance to spread the 7 Mitzvah of the sons of Noah according to Judaism.
(And it is true that there are Sage midrashi who say that Abraham our father fulfilled the mitzvot of Sages, but it is clear that it is only him and not the one who converted)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. If you want to take this angle, then may I recommend the Rambam in Hilchot Melachim that Moshe was commanded to enforce the 7 Noahide Laws among non Jews?

Comment: I barely understand English so I'm using a translation and maybe that's why I don't understand what you mean to ask.

And if you mean to ask whether today's rabbinic halacha is as written by Maimonides

So the answer is that rabbinic Judaism does see this as an important value even today (Chabad Chassidim have special plans for this)

Comment: אמרתי שטוב שתשובתך תכלול את הלכות מלכים רמב"ם ח' י' "וכן צוה משה רבנו מפי הגבורה לכף את כל באי העולם לקבל מצות שנצטוו בני נח"

Comment: This is broadly correct - in principle it is good to enforce/encourage non-Jews keeping the 7 mitzvos, but not acceptance of Judaism. I would caveat that whether this should be carried out in practice today is another question to which different approaches are taken.

Answer (score 1):

Maimonides wrote that we should imitate Abraham. And, what did Abraham do? Abraham proselytized. He made converts. He sat in the front of his tent, waiting to teach about God to anvone willing to listen.

Therefore, it is not surprising that Jews used to proselvtize. In fact, it got so bad that Rome banned Jews from seeking converts. Everyone was proselytizing; there were even Buddhist in the city of Alexandria.

Nothing in Judaism is against proselytizing. So, why don’t Jews seek converts today? One reason is that  Jews are taught that one not need to be Jewish to have a share in world to come. This is true. However, Maimonides makes it clear that non-Jews must observe the Noahide laws and, for the right reasons. There is another reason why Jews stopped making converts. Once mysticism was introduced into Judaism some Jews began to fancy that they were biologically superior to non-Jews. They feared bringing in non-Jews into their community may dilute the “blood.” Lastly, Jews didn't proselvtize out of fear. Not because not allowed.

My own personal view is that Jews should activity be seeking converts purely for academic reasons. Academically, you will agree that 2+2=4, and not 5. It is the same with the Torah. If your convinced that the Torah is true then why not share that wisdom with everyone else? If you found the cure to cancer you would publish it for all. It behooves you to want to share God’s Torah with the world.

Judaism is not a race. Judaism is a religion. The Torah is clear that there is one law for the convert and the born Jew. Abraham was a Gentile. Abraham was not a Jew, but a Noahide. God never "recreated" man since Adam (making a superior one called the Jew); all humans are identical. We all come from Adam and Eve. We are all identical. Both King David and the messiah descend from Ruth the convert. Ruth was a gentile who converted and Kings David and Solomon, as well as the Messiah descend from her. We see from here that gentiles have the same capacity to become the greatest leaders as those who are born to Jewish parents. We are all identical.

Thus, Jews should proselytize. Put differently, we are never commanded not to proselytize. There is no Torah law or rabbinical law barring us from proselytizing non-Jews.

Comment: Wonderful answer.

Comment: @ddas91600 Thank you.  I’m glad you liked what I wrote.

Comment: Thank you for sharing it. You resoundingly made your point when you wrote, "If you found the cure to cancer you would publish it for all. It behooves you to want to share God’s Torah with the world."

Comment: @ddas91600 I'm glad we agree. Yes, I do think that if we are convinced that we have the Word of God, we should share it with the world. If we are convinced that the Torah is the cure to all the troubles in the world, if it can make the world a better place, we have a religious duty to spread Torah. We do this by setting an example and teaching Torah to non-Jews. Even making converts.

Comment: I upvoted because I agree that in the past, there were Jews who did seek converts. Historical sources attest to this, to my knowledge. However, that doesn't mean we should do so today. It has become considerably more difficult to differentiate between honest converts and those who convert for various material incentives.

Comment: @Harel13 Thank you for the upvote. You are correct, it is more difficult to tell. However, I still think 90% of people are sincere. Most people turn to Islam or Christianity because they are not even aware that Judaism accepts converts.